# I can't switch on both coils in double arc lighter transformer

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, high-frequency, diy

I was trying to make DIY plasma lighter (and kind of made it too) but I can't figure out something.

The transformer has 2 primary and 2 secondary coils so I made a NE555 signal generator with 36 kHz frequency + %50 duty cycle. Then I added a 2N3904-06 pair to drive the IRFP-460 mosfet, still works fine.  As soon as I try to supply both coils, one of them automatically turns off. Why?

I'm not asking for how can I build this DIY plasma lighter etc. I'm just asking what's the reason behind it. I just want to learn why this could happen. Like normally if I connect two transformers paralel, current input will raise but each transformer should have same output.

[image: Double Arc Lighter Transformer]

Comment: have you tried connecting the primaries in series?

Comment: Yes and it made extremely weak arcs but high current consumption. I also tried to connect one positive and one negative (coil inputs) to Vcc then connect other positive and negative wires to MOSFETs. Weirdly, both coils worked at once (sometimes they don't, sometimes they do ) but caused a little bit over current and some high frequency noise (I couldn't find the source). Any other wiring combinations never worked.

Comment: schematic needed ... with dot notation on the transformer windings. Are you using the classic push-pull primary circuit?